# Using getline to get input and check if that is CTRL-D in C

Tags: c

im pretty new to c and bascially the problem im having is this currently i have this

```
  char* buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LINE);
  size_t n=MAX_LINE;
  getline(&buf, &n, stdin);
```

How do i check buf in order to see when CTRL-D has been entered?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

^D will send an EOF on stdin.

From the manpage:

```
   On success, getline() and getdelim() return the number of characters read, including the delimiter character, but not includ‐
   ing the terminating null byte.  This value can be used to handle embedded null bytes in the line read.

   Both functions return -1 on failure to read a line (including end-of-file condition).
```

Comment: If some characters are typed before pressing `CTRL+D`, `getline` won't return `-1`.

Comment: You'll still get those characters before the final `-1` is delivered though.